# Request ajax is running after reload page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I'm a problema w\ my ajax request. I have a php that executing with open_proc (this process wait a input some times). If I reload the page before this input my request stay runnig. In my reloaded page I'm getting two response (one by old resquest and outher of new request). Obs: The response is in a file that this php read and write.

--- more details

The main php execute the code with open_proc. This php write data in outputs files and read of input file. In my html I get data of output files and show in screen. But with two runing of php, my data in output file is doubled.

**How I can abort the old request?**

Comment: You could send some sort of token with the request. Then check it when the request returns and ignore it if the tokens don't match.

Comment: My php write and read data in a file. The token in my html/js don't fix the problem.

The main php execut the code with open_proc. This php write data in outputs files and read of inputfile. In my html I get data of output files and show in screen.  

But with two runing of php, my data in output file is doubled.

Comment: Ajax is client side. (I assume you mean proc_open) is server side. If it's a client side issue, you could use a token to ignore unwanted responses. If it's a server side issue, you could lock or rename the file on open/close, so that it's only accessible by one request at a time.

Comment: Hi @PoorlyWrittenCode I'm making this inspired by your first comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used token value in file names to control execution!